# jQuery: Exclude "this" from a list of results

Tags: jquery

As a drag event stops, I must find if my div collides with any other node. So, on the "stop" event, I write a loop that will check for collisions with items of the same type.

```
$('.article').draggable({

    stop: function(event, ui){

        $(".article").each(function (i) {

            if(this == ui.helper){
                return;
            }

            // Test collisions
        });         
    }
});
```

Now, I can't find the way to exclude itself from that loop. I expected this and ui.helper to be the same, but they're considered separate elements. How should I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: How can your elements collide? Can you provide us a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Your example doesn't work because `this` is a raw DOM node, and ui.helper is a jQuery object. Also, you can't compare two jQuery objects: `$('body') === $('body') // false`.

Comment: @AlexanderV.B. using the function found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you want to exclude `this` from `$('.article')`. If so, this can easily be achieved with the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) method:

```
$('.article').not(this).each(function (i) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way when the results are siblings within the same parent

```
$(this).index() == $(ui.helper).index()
```