# Detecting whether two divs overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, collision, gamequery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect if two divs touch with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery)

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to detect if two divs are overlapping.
I tried the gamequery plugin and used it like this:

```
$("#" + checkform).collision("#" + checkform + "w").each(function(){
    alert("Collision");
});
```

Would you use the gamequery plugin and/or how would you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is already a query here having an answer : [How to detect if two divs touch with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery)

For reference I copy the code here:

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
      var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you flagged this question as duplicate of the other one.

Comment: what about if any one of element rotated ? how to verify that rotated element is overlapping or not ?

Answer (score 17):

Use `getBoundingClientRect()` on each element, and see if they overlap that way. No jQuery needed.