# Generate random boxes without overlapping. Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, overlap

i used this random function to generate the top and the left position.
how do i generate the numbers such that the boxes dont overlap with each other.

```
this.posX = Math.floor((Math.random() * 850) + 1);
this.posY = Math.floor((Math.random() * 450) + 1);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ftw68b6f/2/

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732875/randomly-positioned-divs-with-no-overlapping

Comment: This is a working solution that might suit you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707669/trying-to-create-x-number-of-random-rectangles-by-iterating-through-loop-but-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707669/trying-to-create-x-number-of-random-rectangles-by-iterating-through-loop-but-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent them from overlapping initially, however you can add a while loop that checks whether the current chosen position overlaps with any other box, and if it is the case select a new random location.

If you use this option you have to be aware that when the screen becomes fuller the loop takes longer and longer, and potentially infinitely long if no more boxes fit.