# Check if a div touches another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made margin of 2 divs move (using variable and variable++ or -- with style attribute in js to change margin) Like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Game</title>
        <style>
            body{
                position: absolute;
                background: #f00;
            }
            .point{
                position: absolute;
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
                background: #fff;
                border-radius: 10px;
                margin: 0px 0 0;
            }
            .player{
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                width: 200px;
                height: 20px;
                background: #0005ff;
                margin: 550px 550px 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var num = 550;
            $(document).keydown(function (event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    // Left Arrow              
                    case 37: num = num-- - 15;
                        document.getElementById('player').style.margin = '550px ' + num + 'px 0px';
                        break;
                    // Right Arrow              
                    case 39: num = 15 + num++;
                        document.getElementById('player').style.margin = '550px ' + num + 'px 0px';
                        break;
                }
            });
            var nump = 0;
            $(document).load(function () {
                nump++;
                document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 0px 0px';
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="point" id="point"></div>
        <div class="player" id="player"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I got problem about moving div named point.The div, **point** is not moving when I use `$(document).load` but the other div works. How can I fix that?

My second question is how can i check when div "point" touch div "player" then i'll return div point to the start and make a loop.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery

Comment: Thank you, now i still stuck in the other question..

Comment: try `$(window).load` but your code above will only move `point` by 1px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to move the point

```
var nump = 0;
        var touch = false;
        var flagtouch;
        $(document).ready(function () {
        flagtouch = setInterval(function(){
            movePoint(nump);
        },1000);        
        });
        function  movePoint()
        {
            document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 0px 0px';
            touch = chekTouch();   // check whether the divs touches and return true if touched
            if(touch)
            {
              clearInterval(flagtouch);
            }
            else
            {
            nump = nump+5;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've figure out the move but now i still havn't succed to check when div touch another div. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question:

With http://api.jquery.com/position/, you can known the position of both divs, and as you know too the width and height of the elements, you can calculate the region occupied by each element, and then when the elements touch each other.