# jQuery/Javascript Check for text-Overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is any good way to check wether the texts of two html elements overlap?
Carification: Checking for overlap between elements is no Problem I want to check wether the actual texts inside 2 Elements overlap.

Say I have the elements

```
<span id="green">Green is my cÔlor</span>
<span id="blue">blue is my color</span>
```

How could I check wether the texts of those 2 elements overlap? 
We can assume I have access to the jQuery Object of the given elements.

Edit:
What I'm trying to say is that I can detect wether the borders of elements intercect, but in case of text there is the possibility that a good part of the space above and below each character is "unused".

Comment: "Checking for overlap between elements is no Problem I want to check wether the actual texts inside 2 Elements overlap" this statement is not entirely clear, it's confusing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getPositions(elem) {
    var clientRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return [
        [ clientRect.left, clientRect.left + clientRect.width ],
        [ clientRect.top, clientRect.top + clientRect.height ]
    ];
}


function intersect(elemA, elemB) {
    var posA = getPositions(elemA),
        posB = getPositions(elemB),
        isOverlap = false;

    if (posA[0][0] < posB[0][1] && posA[0][1] > posB[0][0] &&
        posA[1][0] < posB[1][1] && posA[1][1] > posB[1][0])
        isOverlap = true;

    return isOverlap;
}
```

Comment: getBoundingClientRect returns the rectangle of whole element, not a text inside it.

Comment: I agree with your offer to use Element.getClientRects()

Comment: Thank you ;) What about to vote my answer if you agree with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [Element.getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects) method which returns a collection of rectangles that indicate the bounding rectangles for each box in a client.

The returned value is a collection of ClientRect objects, one for each CSS border box associated with the element. Each ClientRect object contains read-only left, top, right and bottom properties describing the border box, in pixels, with the top-left relative to the top-left of the viewport. For tables with captions, the caption is included even though it's outside the border box of the table.