# How can I make this code (detecting when two divs touch) display a div instead of a true/false output?

Tags: jquery, html

So... This code works perfectly: http://bit.ly/1ONVMqQ (credit to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54838/bc) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery))

I'm probably just really dumb, but is there a way that I can make it so that code displays a div when the divs touch instead of just a true/false output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
    $('#div3').hide();
 }
 else{
    $('#div3').show();
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/br0apwep/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) {
    // todo if two div are separate
    // hide div here
} else {
    // todo if two div touch each other
    // show div here
}
```