# Checking to see if animated images overlap with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been able to check if two images have the same top css value with:

```
if($('#pic').top == $('#pic1').top){
        alert("You lose");
    }
```

But I want to check if they overlap, so they will not necessarily have the same top value. So, I've tried this:

```
if(parseInt($('#pic').top) < parseInt($('#pic1').top) + 99){
        alert("You lose");
    }
```

It does not work. How can I fix this?
Note: I am using 99 because the height of the images are 100.

Comment: There is a similar question in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery

Comment: I can't imagine your code would work in the first place since `object.top` isn't anything valid.

Comment: Shikkediel yes, the first snippet of code actually works.

Comment: I think you are getting `undefined == undefined` there... so it only appears to be so. That is probably why the second one doesn't work. You could give `$('#pic').offset().top` a try. Then there's also no need to parse them as integer because that will already return a value without pixels.