# How to debug overlapping div elements?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, developer-tools

I am looking for a guideline to check when div( using bootstrap grid or not ) elements are overlapping. So far, I have checked the position and mismatched tags using chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for collision detection. The following Javascript code shows how to detect overlapping HTML div tags. 
Please find more here: [How to detect overlapping elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419134/how-to-detect-if-two-divs-touch-with-jquery)

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
  var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
  var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
  var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
  var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
  var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}
```