# How to make event when two images touch each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a game with html, css and javascript. I am searching that is there any way to make an event with javascript when two images touches, enters, passes over etc each other.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704978/how-to-trigger-an-event-when-elements-divs-images-touch-each-other

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is the images have animation to move, so we can not calculate the position. Do you have any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on your own: https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Most likely if you arn't using any kind of engine you will have to.