# Appear text when one div is on top of the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make some kind of "game" and what I want to do is to when I move around a div, to get notified when the moving red div is on top of the static green div.

*By "notified" I mean setting the paragraphs display property to "block" or even my a console.log() , it's not that important how I get the message.*

PS: You can move around the red block with your up,left,right,down arrows.

Here's my code:

```js
var keys = {};
        keys.UP = 38;
        keys.LEFT = 37;
        keys.RIGHT = 39;
        keys.DOWN = 40;

    /// store reference to character's position and element
    var character = {
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      speedMultiplier: 2,
      element: document.getElementById("character")
    };

    /// key detection (better to use addEventListener, but this will do)
    document.body.onkeyup = 
    document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
      if (e.preventDefault) { 
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
        e.returnValue = false; 
      }
      var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
      keys[kc] = e.type == 'keydown';
    };

    /// character movement update
    var moveCharacter = function(dx, dy){
      character.x += (dx||0) * character.speedMultiplier;
      character.y += (dy||0) * character.speedMultiplier;
      character.element.style.left = character.x + 'px';
      character.element.style.top = character.y + 'px';
    };

    /// character control
    var detectCharacterMovement = function(){
      if ( keys[keys.LEFT] ) {
        moveCharacter(-5, 0);
      }
      if ( keys[keys.RIGHT] ) {
        moveCharacter(5, 0);
      }
      if ( keys[keys.UP] ) {
        moveCharacter(0, -5);
      }
      if ( keys[keys.DOWN] ) {
        moveCharacter(0, 5);
      }
    };

    /// update current position on screen
    moveCharacter();

    /// game loop
    setInterval(function(){
      detectCharacterMovement();
    }, 1000/24);
```

```css
        #character {
    position: absolute;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    background: red;
    z-index:99;
}
#container{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#character2{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
#notifier{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
        <div id="character"></div>

        <div id="character2"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="notifier"> Red div is on top of the yellow div</p>
```

Comment: Get the position of the green div and its length and height. Then just do a check for bounds, if overlapping log to console (or take other appropriate action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56869637/16688813) so that the message is displayed when the red `div` is on top of the other :

```js
var keys = {};
keys.UP = 38;
keys.LEFT = 37;
keys.RIGHT = 39;
keys.DOWN = 40;

/// store reference to character's position and element
var character = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  speedMultiplier: 2,
  element: document.getElementById("character")
};

var is_colliding = function(div1, div2) {
  var d1_height = div1.offsetHeight;
  var d1_width = div1.offsetWidth;
  var d1_distance_from_top = div1.offsetTop + d1_height;
  var d1_distance_from_left = div1.offsetLeft + d1_width;

  var d2_height = div2.offsetHeight;
  var d2_width = div2.offsetWidth;
  var d2_distance_from_top = div2.offsetTop + d2_height;
  var d2_distance_from_left = div2.offsetLeft + d2_width;

  var not_colliding =
    d1_distance_from_top <= div2.offsetTop ||
    div1.offsetTop >= d2_distance_from_top ||
    d1_distance_from_left <= div2.offsetTop ||
    div1.offsetLeft >= d2_distance_from_left;

  return !not_colliding;
};

/// key detection (better to use addEventListener, but this will do)
document.body.onkeyup = 
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
  if (e.preventDefault) { 
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    e.returnValue = false; 
  }
  var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
  keys[kc] = e.type == 'keydown';
};

/// character movement update
var moveCharacter = function(dx, dy){
  character.x += (dx||0) * character.speedMultiplier;
  character.y += (dy||0) * character.speedMultiplier;
  character.element.style.left = character.x + 'px';
  character.element.style.top = character.y + 'px';
  
  if(is_colliding(character.element, document.getElementById("character2"))) {
    document.getElementById("notifier").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("notifier").style.display = "none";
  }
};

/// character control
var detectCharacterMovement = function(){
  if ( keys[keys.LEFT] ) {
    moveCharacter(-5, 0);
  }
  if ( keys[keys.RIGHT] ) {
    moveCharacter(5, 0);
  }
  if ( keys[keys.UP] ) {
    moveCharacter(0, -5);
  }
  if ( keys[keys.DOWN] ) {
    moveCharacter(0, 5);
  }
};

/// update current position on screen
moveCharacter();

/// game loop
setInterval(function(){
  detectCharacterMovement();
}, 1000/24);
```

```css
#character {
    position: absolute;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    background: red;
    z-index:99;
}
#container{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#character2{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
#notifier{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="character"></div>

    <div id="character2"></div>
</div>
<p id="notifier"> Red div is on top of the yellow div</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkCollision(rect, character) {
    if (rect.x < character.x + character.width &&
        rect.x + rect.width > character.x &&
        rect.y < character.y + character.height &&
        rect.height + rect.y > character.y) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This function evaluates if two rectangles are colliding, but you need to provide the width and height for each game entity.

You can also use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the css values.

But if you really want to do a game, you probably should restart using a game engine like [Phaser](https://phaser.io) for example.